# Android IAP. Selling items with different prices

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm developing the application for Android. This application will give the opportunity to buy built-in games (text quests). There is the  site on which they are sold and API that returns prices of games data. Can we somehow accept payments without creating a list of available products in the Google Play Developer Console? Point is that full list creating and keeping them  is very difficult, the price of products may vary, or the person will have some  discount coupon. Support all  discounts and prices  list   will be very difficult.

Comment: primarily opinion based! See this before asking a question! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Google have just released their latest Developer guidelines.

You will find what is and is not permitted there.

https://play.google.com/about/monetization.html#payments